# How to Calculate a Percent in an AggregateResult Method

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, aggregateresult

I am using a custom controller for a Visualforce page on a custom object (Quote__c). I have an AggregateResult method that sums 3 amount fields to show grand totals on my VF page.  I would like to add another field that shows a percentage showing the result of (Final_Price__c / List_Price__c) * 100.  Can anyone help with the syntax on how this can be accomplished?  I assume I have to do it as part of my QuoteGrand list, I'm just not sure how.

Controller:

```
public class CalculateQLISummary{
    String quoteId;
    public list<Quote__c> listQLI{get;set;} 

    public CalculateQLISummary(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        quoteId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }

    public void init(){
        //Used to show the Quote products on the VF page
        listQLI = [
            SELECT Opportunity__r.Id, Must_Be_Checked__c, Name, Quote_Code__c, 
                Contract_Year__c, List_Price__c, Final_Price__c, Unweighted_Amount__c, 
                Discount__c,QLI_Impact__c, Size__c, Number_of_Users__c,
                Number_of_Transactions__c, Cyber_Size__c, Uplift__c
            FROM Quote__c
            WHERE Opportunity__r.Id =:quoteId 
                AND Must_Be_Checked__c=FALSE
        ];
    }

    public List<AggregateResult> QuoteTotal{
        get{
            if (QuoteTotal == null) {
                QuoteTotal = [
                    SELECT Contract_Year__c cy, sum(List_Price__c) lp, sum(Final_Price__c) fp, 
                        sum(Unweighted_Amount__c) uw
                    FROM Quote__c
                    WHERE Opportunity__r.Id =:quoteId
                    GROUP BY Contract_Year__c
                ];
            }

            return qt;
        }

        set;
    }          


    public List<AggregateResult> QuoteGrand{
        get{
            List<AggregateResult> grand = [
                SELECT Contract_Year__c cy, sum(List_Price__c) lp, sum(Final_Price__c) fp, 
                    sum(Unweighted_Amount__c) uw
                FROM Quote__c
                WHERE Opportunity__r.Id =:quoteId
                GROUP BY Contract_Year__c
            ];

            return grand;
        }

        set;
    }          

    public PageReference Cancel(){
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/' + quoteId);
        return pg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Roll-Up

You can get rid of your second query and the need for any code to get the information you want by using roll ups. Create a roll-up field that summerizes the `listprice` and `finalprice` fields and then create a formula to do the math:

```
(opp.grandFinalPrice__c / opp.grandListPrice__c) * 100
```

If you can't use roll-ups then continue reading.

### Code

The first issue I see is that you run the same query twice.

```
SELECT Contract_Year__c cy, sum(List_Price__c) lp, sum(Final_Price__c) fp, 
    sum(Unweighted_Amount__c) uw
FROM Quote__c
WHERE Opportunity__r.Id =:quoteId
GROUP BY Contract_Year__c
```

I **think** in your second query you meant to remove the `GROUP BY` as the word "grand" seems to imply you don't want it seperated by year.

In that case, your comment

> I assume I have to do it as part of my QuoteGrand list

Tells me you only care about this percentage as a whole. So with that in mind this is what you'll want to do:

```
List<AggregateResult> grand = [
    SELECT Contract_Year__c cy, sum(List_Price__c) lp, 
        sum(Final_Price__c) fp, sum(Unweighted_Amount__c) uw
    FROM Quote__c
    WHERE Opportunity__r.Id =:quoteId
];

// Keep in mind that without the grouping, there is only 1 result
Opp.customField__c = (grand[0].get("fp")/grand[0].get("lp")) * 100;
```

That should be pretty much all  you need to do.

**As an Aside** You should get ride of the loop from your `QuoteTotal` getter. You shouldn't do anything other than return the result of the query. Also you should consider null checks in your getters so that you only run the query once. Lastly, you shouldn't be using a new list, you should be assigning the result of the query to the list for which the getter is assigned and returning that lists value. Something like:

```
public List<AggregateResult> QuoteTotal{
    get{
        if (QuoteTotal == null) {
            QuoteTotal = [
                SELECT Contract_Year__c cy, sum(List_Price__c) lp, sum(Final_Price__c) fp, 
                    sum(Unweighted_Amount__c) uw
                FROM Quote__c
                WHERE Opportunity__r.Id =:quoteId
                GROUP BY Contract_Year__c
            ];
        }

        return QuoteTotal;
    }

    set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did edit my code to remove the duplication. I am getting an error "Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments..." for the Opp.customField line you suggested.  It's off because both fields I am using are decimals (1 is a straight decimal, the other is a formula decimal)

Comment: I believe the error is because they are stored as objects, try to typecast them as such `(Decimal) grand.get("fp")`

Comment: Thanks. Now a new error: "Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String) from the type List<AggregateResult>"

Comment: I don't see any obvious reasons that error would appear with the code I provided above. That being said you should learn to troubleshoot those types of issues on your own, you'll rarely find 100% working copy/pasta code on this site. We don't aim to do things for you we aim to give you guidance to do them for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear I am trying to accomplish this myself, including the troubleshooting. Sometimes I am not as clear on syntax or placement of statements, which the people on this site are great resources to help through that. Thanks for your assistance.